# better way concept to use a Model with inheritance in a form with MVC

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, razor, model-view-controller

I want best technique in architecture MVC, to operate with a child class, I try not use more parameters, only a model, i cant use interface:

**Model - parent example:**

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set;  }
}
```

**Model - child example:**

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public String Hair {get;set;}
}
```

**View Sender example SenderDog.cshtml:**

```
@model WebAppHerencia.Models.Dog
```

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

```
@Html.LabelForModel()
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Hair)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Hair)
<input name="submitSend" type="submit" value="send"/>
```

}

**View Receibe Example ReceiveDog.cshtml:**

```
    @model WebAppHerencia.Models.Dog

<h2>Receive Dog</h2>
@Html.LabelForModel()
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Hair)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Hair)
```

**The problem: Controller**

```
    public ActionResult SendDog(Animal model)
    {
        if (Request.Form["submitSend"]!=null)
        {
            var p = model as Dog; 
            return RedirectToAction("ReceiveDog",p);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ReceiveDog(Dog perro)
    {
        return View(perro);
    }
```

I try send model of type Dog in Action of controller (SendDog(Animal a)) wait a Animal (parent), i know that cant pass exactly a child of this way, but I do not know how to do it in the best way... and not use another param..

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5hIk.png)

my scaffolding example
[scaffolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7PDd.png)

Comment: A controller should accept what your model is. Why would you  need to accept a base class type?

Comment: Using example for explain it..I need it because i need acept any animal or dogs or cats or...

Comment: You could probably accept a more general [`FormCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of `Animal` and then deserialize the fields into whatever you want but I would not say that is good design. I think if you need to accept a base class then you are doing something wrong, like trying to use a controller for multiple things?

Comment: When the controller argument is `Animal` you're telling it to look at the received form data and use whatever is needed to create an instance of `Animal`. Everything else will be ignored.

Comment: Maybe can be interesting have multiple controllers for Animal Bases, or maybe have a Action function in a controler for each one type of Animal. I wanted use only one action function for all Animal. One Elephant can have attribute's that dog not...

Comment: @ScottHannen yes i know, i need maybe a class of Animal with all atribute that i need...